# How to define variable in .less file in magento2

Tags: magento2

**Compilation from source error on using using php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy after installation in magento 2.0.7:**

frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/TemplateMonster_Megamenu/fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/l
ess/animated.less
variable @fa-css-prefix is undefined in file C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/TemplateMonster_Megamenu/fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/less/animated.less in animated.less on line 4, column 2

2| // --------------------------

3|

4| .@{fa-css-prefix}-spin {

5|   -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;

6|           animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;

> | }

I don't understand where and how to define the variable @fa-css-prefix in magento2 .less file

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento LESS variable file is already provided by Magento. Follow below path:

yourMagentoSetup\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source_variables.less

After this you can copy or directly create a custom theme web folder such as below path:

yourMagentoSetup\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source_variables.less

Now paste this file.

You can also create a new variable such as,

```
// Spacing
@section_horiontal_pad: 40px;
@section-vertical-pad: 60px;
```